# No recibo el mail para resetear la nueva contraseña, django 2.1

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Estoy tratando de realizar la restauración de contraseña, utilizando el sistema de autenticación de django, no recibo el mensaje en gmail para poder cambiar la nueva contraseña, aquí esta el código, tengo los templates correctos y todos funcionan bien

setting.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'

EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'migmail@gmail.com'

EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'micontraseña'

EMAIL_PORT = 587

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = '[Test mail]'
```

urls.py

```
path('password_reset/', views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
path('password_reset/done/', views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),

path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'), 
path('reset/done/', views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete')
```

Comment: sospecho que es la configuracion de GMAIL,

Comment: quiza tambien revisaste tu correo en spam.

Comment: revise mis correos de spam tampoco esta ahi @DiegoAvila

Answer (score 0):

Saludos te sugiero lo siguiente:

En **settings.py**:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = ‘django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend’
EMAIL_HOST = ‘smtp.gmail.com’
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ‘mi_cuenta@gmail.com’
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ‘miclave123’
```

ahora en **Gmail** debes permitir acceder al correo desde aplicaciones poco seguras:

[acceso a cuentas desde aplicaciones poco seguras](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255)

Espero te sirva fue algo que me sirvió a mi..suerte..!!

Comment: cuando pongo `EMAIL_BACKEND = ‘django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend’ `                                          
 me tira este error : Module "django.core.mail.backends.smtp" does not define a "Emailbackend" attribute/class ,,, por eso lo cambie a `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend`